# How to post a variable with a number for name

Tags: php, post

I know this is bad form, but we can't change the hidden input name as it is set by SalesForce. I have a form with an input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="00N5000000XXXXX" value="Demo_Account" />
```

and my PHP to post to them via cURL

```
$00N5000000XXXXX = $_POST['00N5000000XXXXX'];
```

which obviously won't work as it has number for a variable name.

When I change the name to:

```
$Foo = $_POST['00N5000000XXXXX'];
```

the back end doesn't work because it is expecting the form to submit a value with a name of 00N5000000XXXXX, not Foo or whatever I want to call it.

Obviously, Im not a PHP developer but need some advice on how to get around this.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what your back end expects, but PHP variables can't start with a number. Sounds like you need to fix the backend. :)

Comment: Already know. "which obviously won't work as it has number for a variable name."

Comment: OP knows that, read the question: *"..which obviously won't work as it has number for a variable name."*

Comment: Cmon, "I know this is bad form, but we can't change the hidden input name as it is set by SalesForce."

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: Can you link me to the documentation that says that?

Comment: We need more information about your backend to help you fix this. Basically, what is your backend expecting?

Comment: @AmalMurali [Not completely correct per se, but horrible as it goes against the standard](http://codepad.org/P2p56UD2).

Comment: @h2ooooooo: I'm aware, but that's not really relevant in this case.

Comment: The backend is a CRM system that generates these tags to put in a form. I don't have direct access to SalesForce, as we're doing this on behalf of a partner. It is expecting an element to be submitted with the name of "00N5000000XXXXX"

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Why do you need to put this into a variable before posting it to `cURL`? Just access `$_POST` directly.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: They're probably talking about the `name` **attribute**. The variable name can be whatever you choose.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Im submitting it to another server, basically it's the only way I know how to do it. Please explain

Comment: @AmalMurali - yes it is the name attribute, when I change the var name to something that works, its not submitting what is expected. Or, most likely, I don't know how to do it correctly

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Salesforce most likely don't run PHP on their server, or they don't extract them into variables. You don't need to turn it into a variable to post it with cURL. `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '0000001234=foo');`?

Comment: *"as it is set by SalesForce."* - I'm glad I wasn't the bright one who came up with that concept. I for one, wouldn't work in this town again, if I came up with a naming convention such as that.

Comment: yeah it seems to be a pain in the ass.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign I agree with [What Amal said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430028/how-to-post-a-variable-with-a-number-for-name#comment28806024_19430028) - You can probably set your name attribute with a lettered prefix, while keeping the `$_POST` attribute intact.

Comment: @h2ooooooo When I use the solution you have, I get the following error in console Wrong parameter count for curl_setopt()

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Sorry - I'm used to using a class wrapper for cURL. Your first parameter needs to be your cURL handle. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '0000001234=foo');`

Comment: @h2ooooooo awesome. I obviously don't know much about cURL. Please post as an answer and I will accept if your into that. At the least, much thanks man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to save it to a variable first:

```
<?php
    $transferPostFields = array(
        '00N5000000XXXXX'
    );

    $postFields = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $transferPostFields)) {
            $postFields[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $curlHandle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curlHandle, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.salesforce.com/whatever/urls/they/use',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postFields)
    ));
    $output = curl_exec($curlHandle);

    echo 'The output we received from SalesForce was: ' . $output;
?>
```

If you want to transfer *all* post fields, simply change the top part (anything above `$curlHandle = curl_init()` to:

```
$postFields = $_POST;
```

If you don't need to go past your own server first, then simply change your form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://api.salesforce.com/whatever/urls/they/use">
```

Comment: thanks man. Can't directly post to a url in the action, we send a copy of the stuff somewhewre else. Its a long and dirty process, but your right on with the postfields.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign You're welcome. Glad you got it working. Make sure that you figure out what to do in case the call to salesforces times out (and make SURE that it does so before your own page times out (`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`), or you'll have duplicate orders/only orders in your own system rather than no orders).